# Any way to have wp_mail not send a “registration denied” email?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm using the [approve new user](https://wordpress.org/plugins/new-user-approve/)plugin and the FAQs say that emails are generated through the wp_mail() function. Is there a way to not send a denied email to users when not approving their registration?

Comment: Did my answer do it?

Comment: @mevius It looks like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [view the plugin source](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/new-user-approve/tags/1.7.1/new-user-approve.php), you'll notice that the `deny_user()` email is sent during the `'new_user_approve_deny_user'` hook. Therefore, you can use the following in your **functions.php** to remove the action:

```
remove_action( 'new_user_approve_deny_user', array( pw_new_user_approve(), 'deny_user' ) );
```

Read more about the `remove_action()` function [in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action).

Comment: Awesome, it seems to be working. Thanks a lot. Looking at the plugin source I finally understand how and why you did it, so double thanks.